# Rake error while getting stop words list in python

Tags: python, rake-task

I am running the following code

```
from rake_nltk import rake
import operator
stoppath = 'data/stoplists/SmartStoplist.txt'
rake_object = rake.Rake("SmartStopList.txt",5,3,2)
```

But when i run the last line i get the below error

```
rake_object = rake.Rake("SmartStopList.txt",5,3,2)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-12-595e49e89adb>", line 1, in <module>
    rake_object = rake.Rake("SmartStopList.txt",5,3,2)

  File "C:\Users\kris\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rake_nltk\rake.py", line 64, in __init__
    self.to_ignore = set(chain(self.stopwords, self.punctuations))

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I am nt sure why am i getting this error. Need help on the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `__init__`

```
def __init__(
    self,
    stopwords=None,
    punctuations=None,
    language="english",
    ranking_metric=Metric.DEGREE_TO_FREQUENCY_RATIO,
    max_length=100000,
    min_length=1,
)
```

The 5 is going to `punctuations` parameter which is expected to be a list, not to `ranking_metric`. Use the parameter names

```
rake_object = rake.Rake("SmartStopList.txt", ranking_metric=5, max_length=3, min_length=2)
```

By the way `stopwords` is also expected to be a list, you are sending string.

Comment: Thansk a lot this helped but when i run the next line i am getting a attribute error
 ``` 
keywords = rake_object.run(df['Customer_Log'])
``` 
the error i get is
 ```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-15-5b9c8200a16e>", line 1, in <module>
    keywords = rake_object.run(df['Customer_Log'])

AttributeError: 'Rake' object has no attribute 'run'```
Any help in this direction also

Comment: @Krishnamurthy `Rake` It doesn't have `run`. You can look at the [source code](https://github.com/csurfer/rake-nltk/blob/master/rake_nltk/rake.py) to see the available functions and what the do.

Comment: so how do i run rake_object on a dataframe?

Comment: @Krishnamurthy the `run` function belongs to [python-rake](https://pypi.org/project/python-rake/), not `rake_nltk`. If you use this library you can do `df['Customer_Log'].apply(rake_object.run)`

Comment: i have already installed the `python-rake` library in my spyder but when i try to import using this code `import Rake` it is giving me a error saying `no such module exists` am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @Krishnamurthy try `import RAKE` or `from RAKE import Rake`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234256/discussion-between-krishnamurthy-and-guy).